# Implementation of fixed size queue using a ring (cyclic) buffer

Tags: c++, c++14, collections, circular-list

I found myself in need of a fixed size queue and decided to implement one using a ring (cyclic) buffer.

I have tried my best to match the API of [`std::queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue) with the addition of `full()` to test if the queue is full and unable to accept another element.

The code compiles cleanly with: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic --std=c++14 -lgtest -lgtest_main`, it runs and all tests pass on clang 3.9.1. Unfortunately at least GCC 4.9.4 and below cannot compile the header file due to a bug where a `noexcept` specification can't refer to a member.

All comments welcome.

## File: `xtd/fixed_queue.hpp`

```
#ifndef GUARD_INCLUDE_XTD_FIXED_QUEUE_HPP
#define GUARD_INCLUDE_XTD_FIXED_QUEUE_HPP

#include <array>
#include <cstdint>
#include <stdexcept>

namespace xtd {

  template <typename T, std::size_t N>
  class fixed_queue {
  public:
    using value_type = T;
    using reference = value_type&;
    using const_reference = const value_type&;
    using size_type = std::size_t;

    fixed_queue() = default;
    fixed_queue(const fixed_queue& other) { *this = other; }
    fixed_queue(fixed_queue&& other) { *this = std::move(other); }
    ~fixed_queue() { clear(); }

    fixed_queue& operator=(const fixed_queue& other) {
      clear();

      auto i = other.m_read_idx;
      while (i != other.m_write_idx) {
        emplace(*other.get(i));
        i = other.increment_index(i);
      }
      return *this;
    }

    fixed_queue& operator=(fixed_queue&& other) {
      clear();
      while (!other.empty()) {
        emplace(std::move(other.front()));
        other.pop();
      }
      return *this;
    }

    size_type capacity() const { return N; }

    size_type size() const {
      if (empty()) {
        return 0;
      } else if (m_write_idx > m_read_idx) {
        return m_write_idx - m_read_idx;
      } else {
        return N - m_read_idx + m_write_idx + 1;
      }
    }

    void clear() {
      while (!empty()) {
        pop();
      }
    }

    bool full() const { return size() == capacity(); }

    bool empty() const { return m_write_idx == m_read_idx; }

    reference front() { return const_cast<reference>(cthis()->front()); }
    const_reference front() const {
      assert_not_empty("Cannot peek an empty queue!");
      return *get(m_read_idx);
    }

    void pop() {
      assert_not_empty("Cannot pop an empty queue!");
      auto old_idx = m_read_idx;
      m_read_idx = increment_index(m_read_idx);
      get(old_idx)->~value_type();
    }

    void swap(fixed_queue<T, N>& other) noexcept(noexcept(swap(this->m_data, other.m_data))) {
      using std::swap;
      swap(m_data, other.m_data);
      swap(m_write_idx, other.m_write_idx);
      swap(m_read_idx, other.m_read_idx);
    }

    template <typename... Args>
    void emplace(Args&&... args) {
      assert_not_full("Cannot push to a full queue!");
      new (get(m_write_idx)) value_type(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
      m_write_idx = increment_index(m_write_idx);
    }

  private:
    // We add one to the capacity, this avoids the problem that:
    // read_idx == write_idx on both an empty and a full queue.
    // We will never get "truly full" as there will always be one
    // extra space.
    alignas(value_type) std::array<uint8_t, sizeof(value_type) * (N + 1)> m_data;
    size_type m_write_idx = 0;
    size_type m_read_idx = 0;

    auto cthis() const { return const_cast<const fixed_queue<T, N>*>(this); }

    auto assert_not_empty(const char* message) const {
      if (empty()) {
        throw std::runtime_error(message);
      }
    }

    auto assert_not_full(const char* message) const {
      if (full()) {
        throw std::runtime_error(message);
      }
    }

    auto increment_index(size_type i) const { return (i + 1) % (N + 1); }

    auto get(size_type i) { return const_cast<value_type*>(cthis()->get(i)); }
    auto get(size_type i) const { return reinterpret_cast<const value_type*>(m_data.data()) + i; }
  };

  template <typename T, std::size_t N>
  void swap(fixed_queue<T, N>& a, fixed_queue<T, N>& b) noexcept(noexcept(a.swap(b))) {
    a.swap(b);
  }
}

#endif
```

## File: `test/fixed_queue.cpp`

```
#include "xtd/fixed_queue.hpp"

#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <ostream>

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<std::string>& v) {
  os << "[";
  auto first = true;
  for (auto& x : v) {
    if (!first) {
      os << ", ";
    }
    first = false;
    os << x;
  }
  os << "]";
  return os;
}

namespace xtd {
  std::vector<std::string> destructorCalls;
  std::vector<std::string> constructorCalls;
  std::vector<std::string> copyConstructorCalls;
  std::vector<std::string> moveConstructorCalls;

  class TestClass {
  public:
    TestClass(const std::string& name) : m_name(name) { constructorCalls.emplace_back(m_name); }
    TestClass(TestClass&& other) : m_name(std::move(other.m_name)) {
      other.m_name = "--MOVED--";
      moveConstructorCalls.emplace_back(m_name);
    }
    TestClass(const TestClass& other) : m_name(other.m_name) {
      copyConstructorCalls.emplace_back(m_name);
    }
    ~TestClass() { destructorCalls.emplace_back(m_name); }

    bool operator==(const TestClass& other) const { return m_name == other.m_name; }

    const std::string& name() const { return m_name; }

  private:
    std::string m_name;
  };

  class fixed_queue_test : public ::testing::Test {
  protected:
    virtual void SetUp() {
      constructorCalls.clear();
      copyConstructorCalls.clear();
      moveConstructorCalls.clear();
      destructorCalls.clear();
    }
    virtual void TearDown() {}
  };

  TEST_F(fixed_queue_test, CopyAssignmentWithComplexObject) {
    auto cut = fixed_queue<TestClass, 3>();

    // Create a test case that is partially wrapped around.
    cut.emplace("foo");  // index 0
    cut.pop();
    cut.emplace("bar");  // 1
    cut.pop();
    cut.emplace("baz");  // 2
    cut.emplace("boz");  // index 0

    auto copy = fixed_queue<TestClass, 3>();
    copy.emplace("beef"); // make sure old data is cleared
    copy = cut; 

    ASSERT_EQ(cut.size(), copy.size());
    ASSERT_EQ(cut.front().name(), copy.front().name());
    ASSERT_EQ(0, moveConstructorCalls.size());
    ASSERT_EQ(5, constructorCalls.size());
    ASSERT_EQ(2, copyConstructorCalls.size());
    ASSERT_EQ(3, destructorCalls.size());

    ASSERT_EQ("baz", copyConstructorCalls[0]);
    ASSERT_EQ("boz", copyConstructorCalls[1]);
  }

  TEST_F(fixed_queue_test, MoveAssignmentWithComplexObject) {
    auto cut = fixed_queue<TestClass, 32>();

    cut.emplace("foo");
    cut.emplace("bar");
    cut.emplace("baz");
    cut.pop();

    auto copy = fixed_queue<TestClass, 32>();
    copy.emplace("beef");

    copy = std::move(cut);

    ASSERT_EQ(2, copy.size());
    ASSERT_EQ("bar", copy.front().name());
    // std::cout<<moveConstructorCalls<<std::endl;
    ASSERT_EQ(2, moveConstructorCalls.size());
    ASSERT_EQ(4, constructorCalls.size());
    ASSERT_EQ(4, destructorCalls.size());

    ASSERT_EQ("bar", moveConstructorCalls[0]);
    ASSERT_EQ("baz", moveConstructorCalls[1]);

    ASSERT_EQ("foo", constructorCalls[0]);
    ASSERT_EQ("bar", constructorCalls[1]);
    ASSERT_EQ("baz", constructorCalls[2]);
    ASSERT_EQ("beef", constructorCalls[3]);

    ASSERT_EQ("foo", destructorCalls[0]);
    ASSERT_EQ("beef", destructorCalls[1]);
    ASSERT_EQ("--MOVED--", destructorCalls[2]);
    ASSERT_EQ("--MOVED--", destructorCalls[3]);
  }

  TEST_F(fixed_queue_test, EmplacePopWithComplexObject) {
    auto cut = fixed_queue<TestClass, 32>();

    ASSERT_TRUE(constructorCalls.empty());
    ASSERT_TRUE(destructorCalls.empty());

    cut.emplace("foo");

    ASSERT_EQ(1, constructorCalls.size());
    ASSERT_EQ("foo", constructorCalls[0]);
    ASSERT_TRUE(destructorCalls.empty());

    cut.emplace("bar");
    cut.emplace("baz");
    cut.pop();

    ASSERT_EQ(3, constructorCalls.size());
    ASSERT_EQ("bar", constructorCalls[1]);
    ASSERT_EQ("baz", constructorCalls[2]);
    ASSERT_EQ(1, destructorCalls.size());
    ASSERT_EQ("foo", destructorCalls[0]);
  }

  TEST_F(fixed_queue_test, ClearWithComplexObject) {
    constructorCalls.clear();
    destructorCalls.clear();

    auto cut = fixed_queue<TestClass, 32>();

    cut.emplace("foo");
    cut.emplace("bar");
    cut.emplace("baz");
    cut.clear();

    ASSERT_TRUE(cut.empty());
    ASSERT_EQ(0, cut.size());
    ASSERT_EQ(3, constructorCalls.size());
    ASSERT_EQ("foo", constructorCalls[0]);
    ASSERT_EQ("bar", constructorCalls[1]);
    ASSERT_EQ("baz", constructorCalls[2]);
    ASSERT_EQ(constructorCalls, destructorCalls);
  }

  TEST_F(fixed_queue_test, DestructorWithComplexObject) {
    constructorCalls.clear();
    destructorCalls.clear();

    {
      auto cut = fixed_queue<TestClass, 32>();
      cut.emplace("foo");
      cut.emplace("bar");
      cut.emplace("baz");
    }

    ASSERT_EQ(3, constructorCalls.size());
    ASSERT_EQ("foo", constructorCalls[0]);
    ASSERT_EQ("bar", constructorCalls[1]);
    ASSERT_EQ("baz", constructorCalls[2]);
    ASSERT_EQ(constructorCalls, destructorCalls);
  }

  TEST_F(fixed_queue_test, DefaultConstructor) {
    auto cut = fixed_queue<int, 32>();
    ASSERT_EQ(32, cut.capacity());
    ASSERT_TRUE(cut.empty());
    ASSERT_FALSE(cut.full());
    ASSERT_EQ(0, cut.size());
  }

  TEST_F(fixed_queue_test, SimpleUsage) {
    auto cut = fixed_queue<int, 4>();

    cut.emplace(1);
    ASSERT_FALSE(cut.empty());

    cut.emplace(2);
    cut.emplace(3);
    cut.emplace(4);
    ASSERT_EQ(1, cut.front());
    ASSERT_EQ(4, cut.size());
    ASSERT_FALSE(cut.empty());
    ASSERT_TRUE(cut.full());
    ASSERT_EQ(4, cut.capacity());

    cut.pop();
    ASSERT_EQ(2, cut.front());
    ASSERT_EQ(3, cut.size());
    ASSERT_FALSE(cut.full());

    cut.pop();
    ASSERT_EQ(3, cut.front());
    ASSERT_EQ(2, cut.size());

    cut.pop();
    ASSERT_EQ(4, cut.front());
    ASSERT_EQ(1, cut.size());

    cut.pop();
    ASSERT_EQ(0, cut.size());
    ASSERT_TRUE(cut.empty());
  }

  TEST_F(fixed_queue_test, LoopingUsage) {
    const int capacity = 10;
    const int laps = 3;

    for (int window = 1; window <= capacity; ++window) {
      int counter = 0;
      auto cut = fixed_queue<int, capacity>();

      for (int i = 0; i < window; ++i) {
        cut.emplace(counter++);
      }

      try {
        for (int i = 0; i < capacity * laps; ++i) {
          std::string msg = "Window: " + std::to_string(window) + " i=" + std::to_string(i);
          ASSERT_EQ(counter - window, cut.front()) << msg;
          cut.pop();
          cut.emplace(counter++);
          ASSERT_EQ(window, cut.size()) << msg;
        }
      } catch (...) {
        std::cout << "Window: " << window << std::endl;
        throw;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Non Standard Copy Semantics

Interested in why you chose to implement the copy constructor in terms of the copy assignment operator and not the other way around. Noting that the standard way to implement this is the copy and swap idiom (other way around).

I can see this is probably slightly more efficient. But is the decrease in readability worth it. Only you can answer that.

```
fixed_queue(const fixed_queue& other) { *this = other; }
fixed_queue& operator=(const fixed_queue& other) {
  clear();

  auto i = other.m_read_idx;
  while (i != other.m_write_idx) {
    emplace(*other.get(i));
    i = other.increment_index(i);
  }
  return *this;
}
```

The one issue I have with this is that it does not provide the strong exception guarantee and you can't fall back to the original state if something goes wrong.

Though this is correct. I don't like the copy constructor not explicitly initializing the members. Have to go check the rest of the code to make sure the members are initialized reeks of doing things in multiple places.

### Move Semantics

The source of the move can be left in an undefined state (as long as it is valid).

I don't see the need to `pop()` values from the source object. just move them. Poping them adds extra work that is not required. The destructor when called when do all the cleanup required.

```
fixed_queue& operator=(fixed_queue&& other) {
  clear();
  while (!other.empty()) {
    emplace(std::move(other.front()));

    // Don't need this.
    // Though if you do remove this you need to change the above line
    // to get a reference to an internal member.
    other.pop();
  }
  return *this;
}
```

#### Alignment

<strike>Not 100% convinced this works.</strike>

```
alignas(value_type) std::array<uint8_t, sizeof(value_type) * (N + 1)> m_data;
```

<strike>You want the internals of the array (ie. the array members) to be aligned to `value_type`. This is technically aligning the array (not its members). I have not read up on the requirements of the array (so this may work) but this seems a bit doggy.</strike>

Just point this works because `std::array` is a special case (guaranteed to only have one element that aligns with the specified data type). In general aligning containers on their content data type may not work.

### Initialization

```
size_type m_write_idx = 0;
size_type m_read_idx = 0;
```

I prefer the constructor to initialize members. It's easier to spot when things are missed. If you are going to initialize the members in the code then I prefer them near the construcors so that it is easy to spot.

Personally I lay my code out like this:

```
Class
    private   Variables
    public    Constructors/Assignment/Destructors

    public    methods
    protected methods
    private   methods
```

This way I can quickly see if the members have all been initialized.

Comment: @Incomputable: I bet Emily's code is correct. But your linked example does not provide any help. That shows raw (ARRAY OF POD) data being aligned. Emily is trying to align a larger structure whose members could require different alignment. Or the standard may require that Array have a bigger alignment than its contained members? I am not sure.

Comment: Regarding the alignment, 5.3.3/2 guarantees `sizeof(T)*N` is enough storage for N aligned copies. As long as the first copy is aligned, so are the rest; and `alignas()` guarantees the start of the array will be aligned, further more it propagates the alignment restriction of `T` to `fixed_queue`.

Comment: Further more [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) is only allowed to have `T[N]` as it's only non static data member. So it's safe. :)

Comment: Using copy & swap require T to be [Swappable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Swappable). I don't want to put this requirement on T, but strong exception safety would be desirable. I'll see if I can't concoct something. As for the move assignment, the source will be destroyed eventually (as it's r-value reference, probably pretty soon). The destructor will pop all the elements anyway, doing it in the move assignment only moves the work while allowing an easy and clean implementation.

Comment: @Incomputable: Still not relevant. As you are not aligning array objects you are aligning on the content of the array. But the conversation is now mute as we now that array can only contain the array of elements so it will work.

Comment: @EmilyL.: By leaving the pop(int) to the destructor makes things easier as you don't need to worry about destroying `T` as part of the move (this happens afterwords as part of the destructor sequence which happens after the move is completed). Thus you can successfully move and your object is in a consistent state even if the destruction of one of the `T` members fail.